# Keep potential difference fixed for transformer's output

Tags: transformer, impedance-matching

I have a source consisting of V1, R1, L1, and L2 to which my load R2 is attached:

[image: schematic]

For the load, I have 10 or 100 Ohms.

1) R2 = 10  Ohms: Vrms = 315 V, irms = 32 A, P = 10 kW

2) R2 = 100 Ohms: Vrms = 788 V, irms = 8  A, P = 6  kW

How do I adjust the circuit in such a way that for R2 = 10 Ohm, I still have 788 V across R2? I suppose, I have to match impedance in such a way that the supply sees R2 like if it is 100 Ohm instead of 10 Ohm.

I am not allowed to change V1, R1, L1, and L2. That is to say, they should be treaded as a power supply that I can't adjust in any way. I am free to add components across the load R2.

Here are the waveforms:

[image: volts]

[image: curr]

[image: power]

Comment: Your transformer is ideal due to k1 l1 l2 1, so you are just seeing the effect of the drop over R1. Set R1 to 1mohm and test again.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am not allowed to change V1, R1, L1, and L2.

Comment: Then you can't compensate and have to suffer the voltage drop. Thete is no free lunch.

Comment: @winny, is there really no solution? Does it mean that it is a universal rule that as the load value decreases, the voltage drop on the output of the transformer must occur? Now.. say, if I couldn't tinker with R1 but was allowed to add a separate winding L3 onto a transformer (again with perfect coupling) and add components onto it, would there be some solution?

Comment: Add another winding and directly couple it to V1 - that works.

Comment: @Andyaka, how would I choose inductance and what is the idea behind it?

Comment: The idea behind it is that R1 is effectively short circuited. After all you did say we could add components so I chose to add (in effect) a zero ohm resistor across R1 but I did it without touching R1 on both sides. Try it in your sim.

Comment: @Andyaka, ok this works and we push the current through a short away from R1. But is there a more realistic way of dealing with this problem? A new winding on a real-life transformer will have a resistive component, so it solves the problem only in sim. Any ideas?

Comment: This is beginning to look like an XY problem. State the bigger picture.

Comment: @Andyaka, to be more clear, I am looking for a conceptual way to solve the problem of voltage drop across the load on the output of a high-voltage transformer. Adjusting R1 seems like the easiest solution but from the problem statement and from real circuitry one can see that R1 comes with the length of the primary winding (along with V1's output resistance). I'm looking for some practical solution